# Cannot get Meteor app running on fresh install of Ubuntu linux because of missing MongoDB

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to get a project running on Linux. Usually we develop on macOS and I assumed that the setup on Linux was very similar.

The steps I take to get the application on my machine are:

- installed nodejs according to the website via shell script execution
- installed Meteor according to the website via shell script execution
- git checkout [git URL of application]
- cd eaab (eaab = name of application)
- npm install
- mrt install
- npm run start

The package.json contains multiple run scripts, the called start script is defined as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "meteor --settings settings/development.json",
    [removed other scripts not relevant right now]
  },
```

Although all of this works on macOS, on Linux it fails like this:

```
skaupp@developers:~/Workspace/meteor/eaab
>npm run start                                                                                                                                                                                                       (git)-[master] 

> eaab@1.0.0 start /home/skaupp/Workspace/meteor/eaab
> meteor --settings settings/development.json

[[[[[ ~/Workspace/meteor/eaab ]]]]]

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /usr/lib/node_modules/meteor/mongodb/bin/mongod ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! eaab@1.0.0 start: `meteor --settings settings/development.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the eaab@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/skaupp/.npm/_logs/2018-04-05T09_43_23_575Z-debug.log
```

I assume that normally mongodb would be installed during either the general Meteor installation or when running mrt install, but as this doesn't seem to be the case. I might have to either install it manually or change my way of setting up the environment. In either case I am aware that, aside from mongodb, other tools required by Meteor might not be automatically set up.

How can I fix this, or, in other words, what am I missing?

Comment: Did you run `npm install` using an npm binary that has been installed outside of Meteor? Because usually you should use `meteor npm install` to use the Meteor bundled npm. You should also not require an external nodeJs installation as Meteor comes with an own node environment for compatibility reasons. Also `mrt install` is used in rather legacy applications and rarely required in recent Meteor projects. What happens if you create a new meteor project like `meteor create testproject && cd testproject && meteor npm install && meteor` ?

Comment: Good point. It seems like something is entirely wrong with the Meteor setup, as "meteor create testproject" already failes because it cannot open "/usr/lib/node_modules/meteor/examples". Just wondering how this could have happened as I installed Meteor via curl/sh, as mentioned on the website. (Doing it this way on macOS, too, with no problems so far.)

Comment: From reading this I think this goes down to the realm of user permissions. Did you install or run any command with root permissions? This can sometimes be the cause of problems. Meteor usually requires no root.

Comment: I found the issue. I checked out the application from scratch and instead of "npm install" I ran "meteor npm install", just as you suggested in your first comment. "mrt install" was needed, too but now the application works!

Answer (score -1):

Meteor installation is quite simple and very straightforward. You only run the command `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`on a Linux environment. Nothing more. Meteor has its own Node.js and MongoDB packages and they're installed automatically. Meteor will use these packages, by default, not the ones you installed separately. I recommend you to check the official [Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/#quickstart) as it is quite practical and informative.

Comment: I installed Meteor according to the website via shell script execution. I stated that in my question, too.

Comment: In your question you I see many redundant steps which can break your setup. That's why I recommend a clear installation, clearly in my answer. Thousands of people have been installing Meteor and using with any NPM package, in its standard procedure.

Comment: I digged a bit deeper. The root cause is probably not the mongodb itself but a self-hosted meteorite dependency that is installed through the "old" way (therefore the call of mrt install).